# java CallableStatement vs SELECT regards to SQL injection

Tags: java, sql-server, postgresql, sql-injection

I am hoping to understand CallableStatement a little better.
So the case is I have a stored functions in my postgre database.

Calling these functions from java where the parameters are user input (HTTP POST parameters) I have to worry about SQL injections.

So doing this in java:

```
String statementSQL = "SELECT my_function(" + toPostgresString(person.getEmail()) + "," + toPostgresString(person.getPhone()) + "," + toPostgresString(person.getDealType())+ ");";
```

where

```
private static String toPostgresString(String value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
        return POSTGRES.NULL;
    } else {
        return "'" + value + "'";
    }
}
```

The latter method makes sure that all params are treated as strings, but I read that this solutions is still dangerous when params are malicious.

So I tried using CallableStatements as they are said to be safer.

```
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(" { call my_function( ?, ?, ? ) } ");

statement.setString(1, person.email());
statement.setString(2, person.phone());
statement.setString(3, person.getDealType());
statement.execute();
statement.close();
```

**Question:** In both cases SELECT and CallableStatement the params are sent to database function and treated there as datatypes defined by the function itself. CallableStatement only fails when datatypes don't match (in the declared function and the statement.set().

How is CallableStatement actually safer vs SELECT when in both cases the params are treated as string (but between '').

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `PreparedStatement` and `CallableStatement` offer the `setXXX` methods to set parameters. They don't actually sanitize the parameters, they just use a binary type for them on the wire, so the "in both cases the params are treated as string" part is wrong.

`PreparedStatement` also offers some minor performance advantages since the driver will actually create a server side prepared statement after a query has been called enough times.

You should never use a normal `Statement` unless absolutely necessary, and always use the `setXXX` methods since that's what they're for.

Comment: Wait, but then how should I sanitize the parameters? Are the Callable and Prepared only for performance then? Some say the do sanitize and some say they don't. What security do they offer then? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to sanitize them. I just meant that the driver doesn't concatenate the parameters together. It sends them in binary format, so you can't inject SQL there.

Comment: Right, but you could send malicious params as binary as well? They will then be made into string in the database and still be dangerous? I am not really aware of the inner workings of the JDBC.

Comment: No. Because they won't be interpreted as part of the query. Therefore if the parameter contains `'`, it won't be interpreted as the end of a string. There is no string concatenation anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `CallableStatement.setXXX()` sanitizes the parameters for you. So it does more than simple String concatenation.

On the other hand, when you concatenate String, you can expect nasty attacks, like stopping the previous statement, then starting a new one: `'; drop table users; --

See more on [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: So using CallableStatement.setXXX() I don't need to worry about making a separate whitelist for the inputs? The problem is that in addition to the person I have a whole bunch of address components where creating a whitelist for address parts is quite difficult as there can be a lot of different characters in them (numbers , -, : , string, etc).

Comment: I'm afraid you still have to validate your input in terms of business requirements. All that the setXXX() methods do for you is that they protect you from sql injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, and that's fine by me. The only legit way to make the API calls is from a specified client which will automatically sets the address components. I want to protect the db from API calls coming non legit sources and thus they can be rejected by the server by me.